# Is Inferential and Descriptive Statistics for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am starting with Machine Learning and many people suggested that I should first start with Descriptive and Inferential Statistics on Udacity. I started with it. But I have a doubt that is it absolutely necessary to do the courses to learn ML or I can directly start ML?

Comment: No, it is not 100% necessary but it would help. As would a bit of linear algebra.